# Concatenating multiple lists

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have two lists as follows:

```
list1 = [[A, A, A, A][B, B, B, B]]
list2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4][1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I was trying to concatenate their contents using

```
result.append(list1 + list2)
```

I am not getting the result that I was expecting as:

result = [[A1, A2, A3, A4][B1, B2, B3, B4]]

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: You really need to tag the language you're working with in this as people here know just about every language out there and you're likely to either get no answer and get down-voted or get a ton of answers you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Here is one solution,

```
 >>> list1 = [['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
 >>> list2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
 >>> [[i+str(j) for i,j in zip(x,y)] for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]
 [['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4']]
 >>>
```